# Observing all possible values of a discrete random variable with the given probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there's a true random number generator which can output an integer value in [0..N). How many times does it have to be invoked for it to generate every possible value [0..N) at least once, with the given probability P?

For example, for coin clips, there's a 50% probability of seeing both heads and tails in two rounds, 75% probability in three rounds etc. I wonder how to generalize this for a system of N possible outcomes and any given probability P?

Comment: This situation is called the "coupon collector" problem with $n$ coupons.  For some problems you get a more insightful answer by changing the question:  If you ask the expected time to get all coupons the answer is $(n)(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ...+\frac{1}{n})$.  Or, the probability of getting all of them in exactly $n$ picks is $\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}...\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: The probability $p_n$ to generate every possible value at least once in $n$ outputs of the TRNG generating $N$ equiprobable possible values, is $$p_n=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(-1)^k{N\choose k}\left(1-\frac kN\right)^n$$ Thus, for $N$ fixed, when $n\to\infty$, $$1-p_n\sim N\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n$$

Comment: Thanks! Consider posting as an answer so I could accept.